# PySpark Kusto connector without using an AAD app

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-explorer

I am currently using DataBricks and trying to set up a PySpark connect without using an Azure AD application.
I was looking at the provided examples in PySpark [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/blob/master/samples/src/main/python/pyKusto.py), but they all require an `AAD_CLIENT_ID`. I was wondering whether or not there is a way not to use any application?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to give the connector an **AAD token** or using **device authentication** as explained here https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md